# How to Filter or Block Excessive Spam in Site Search

Tags: solspace, supersearch

I'm getting a crazy amount of spam traffic through supersearch. They are all for 13-digit ISBNs (book UPCs). Since we are an online bookstore, I didn't notice it at first, but we're getting about 1000 searches per hour(!) for products obviously unrelated to our website (we sell construction books).

Is there a way I can filter or block this spam? For that matter, is there a way I can find the IP address where these searches are coming from (assuming the IP address is static)?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding [Snaptcha](https://www.putyourlightson.net/snaptcha) to your supersearch form. It really is very good at preventing automated form submissions.

Although supersearch is not supported natively, it is easy to add to any form by just adding the following tag to your template in between your form opening and closing tags:

```
{exp:snaptcha:field}
```

Comment: Looks good, I will check that out!